# after 5 seconds recording stopped in mozilla but working fine in chrome

Tags: html, microphone

HTML5 Microphone capture stops after 5 seconds in Firefox. It is working fine in Chrome. I have taken this code from Github.

```
var audio_context;
var recorder;
var localStream; // line added by me

function startUserMedia(stream) {
    localStream = stream; // line added by me
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

Comment: Post the code or at least link to it

Answer (score 1):

```
var audio_context;
var recorder;

function startUserMedia(stream) {
var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```

change above line to this:

```
var audio_context;
var recorder;
var localStream; // line added by me

function startUserMedia(stream)  {
localStream = stream; // line added by me
var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
```